# finding image id and replacing with clicked button class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, find

```
<div>
    <a class="img1">click1</a><br>
    <a class="img2">click2</a><br>
</div>
<div>
    <img id="img1" src="images/01.png">
    <img id="img2" src="images/02.png">
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$(".yo a").click(function(){
    var class1 = $(this).attr("class");
    $(".yo").find("img").attr("id",class1).css("padding","50px");
})
```

I want to get class name of 'a' tag and find image id with same name and change padding of that image, thanks in advance (sorry for my bad English :p)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//$(".yo").find("img").attr("id",class1).css("padding","50px");
$(".yo").find("img#"+class1).css("padding","50px");
```

but if your element has more than one class (like `class="img-id other-class one-more-class"`) - you should aditionally parse class attribute and decide which one could be an image-id.

maybe check all of them (not optimal but easiest to implement:

```
var class1 = $(this).attr("class").split(/\s+/).map(function(a){return '#'+a;}).join(',');
$(".yo").find('img').find(class1).css("padding","50px");
```

Answer (score 3):

The only part you didn't get right is finding the `img` element by `id` (and there's a simpler way to get the class of the link). To find an element by its ID with jQuery, you use a `#id` selector (the `#` followed by the ID):

```
$(".yo a").click(function(){
    $("#" + this.className).css("padding","50px");
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- find the element whose id matches the class
});
```

Example (in the below, I've added a `return false` to cancel the click so we don't actually follow the link):

```js
$(".yo a").click(function(){
    $("#" + this.className).css("padding","50px");
    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--- find the element whose id matches the class
    return false;
});
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="yo">
  <a href="#" class="img1">one</a>
</div>
<div class="yo">
  <a href="#" class="img2">two</a>
</div>
<div class="yo">
  <a href="#" class="img3">three</a>
</div>
<div class="yo">
  <a href="#" class="img4">four</a>
</div>

<div>
  img 'img1':
  <img id="img1">
</div>
<div>
  img 'img2':
  <img id="img2">
</div>
<div>
  img 'img3':
  <img id="img3">
</div>
<div>
  img 'img4':
  <img id="img4">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: Rather than setting the padding directly on the element, I recommend using a class to control the padding via CSS.